# Construct a Task<TResult> type to be used as return value

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have two methods :

```
public async Task<int> Foo()
{
  return Datetime.Now.Second;
}

public async Task<string> Bar()
{
  return "222";
}
```

and also a Context which has some information about methods:

Context.ReturnValue which is `Task<int>` for Foo() and `Task<string>` for Bar().

Context.MethodInfo MethodInfo for the method I've called.

What I want to do is some mock up things like I want to return 2 for Foo() method based on the type of Context.MethodInfo.ReturnType.

```
Context.ReturnValue = Task<int>.FromResult(2);
```

And I also want this solution to be used for Bar():

```
Context.ReturnValue = Task<string>.FromResult("333");
```

So the problem is how can I construct a `Task<TResult>` variable based on the 
Context.MethodInfo.ReturnType and value.

---

Why I want to do this is I want to cache the return result of method via a CachingAttribute.

```
[CachingAttribute]    
public async Task<int> Foo(){return 1;}
```

This attribute can automatically handle following things:

1. Check the cache value in cache provider like redis.
2. If exists , handle the return value. (This problem exists here)
3. If not , execute the method and put the return value into cache provider.

Then in the usage.
When we call the Foo method like :

```
var result = await Foo();
```

//with caching attribute , result can be a specific value like 10. Then I can add caching capability to any method that I want without changing caller's behavior.

Comment: Return a keyValuePair<int,object>

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? This looks like poor architecture to me. But maybe there is a good reason why you want this?

Comment: Your question it is not clear. Please include some scenarios with the expected outputs, more importantly some code that you have tried.

Comment: I want to cache the return value for methods via a CachingAttribute.

Comment: Sounds like you want to call `Task.FromResult<type>(value)` using reflection. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method).

Answer (score -1):

I've already solved this problem by using dynamic keyword.

Sample code :

```
if (context.IsAsync())
{
    dynamic member = context.ServiceMethod.ReturnType.GetMember("Result")[0];
    dynamic temp = System.Convert.ChangeType(result, member.PropertyType);
    context.ReturnValue = System.Convert.ChangeType(Task.FromResult(temp), context.ServiceMethod.ReturnType);
}
```

Comment: Why use `dynamic`? This seems to be able to be done with reflection. You really should have provided a [mcve] in your question. Then we could have answered quite easily without the need for black magic, er, `dynamic`.

Comment: It's quite complex to show total code here. I also thought that I could solve this problem by using reflection but I couldn't. After searching, I find that maybe I can use dynamic keyword here.

Comment: You didn't get an answer because you didn't provide a [mcve]. Simple as that. The answer you've posted isn't the best. You really should reconsider posting the minimal code

Comment: I've used a lot of third party libraries in my scenario. So it's quite hard for me to generate a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. To get some help here I have no choice but sample code.

Comment: Then it is hard for us to give you an answer. You really should take the time, no matter how hard it might be, to give a [mcve].